# Why Windows 10 fonts looks pixelated in all apps?

Tags: windows-10, display, fonts, integrated-graphics

I have been using Linux and Mac for past 8 years. I installed Windows 10 (October update) today first. And got a nasty surpirse. The default font (which I believe Segoe UI) looks horribly pixelated, broken and what not.

I tried adjusting cleartype twice, updated drivers thrice and tried changing font twice. Nothing helps. On mac and ubuntu, all the fonts even the system ones are so smooth.

Info: Resolution 1366x768. Intel HD 610.

The fonts looks like that. See how thin they are even after adjusting cleartype and the spine of the S and shoulder of C are totally pixelated. [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzwch.png) [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np1Ef.png) [Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IExo6.png)

How do I fix it?

Update: I found out, it's because of Windows' awful DPI calling in basic hd resolution monitors. Although Mac and Linux does the job perfectly in all screens. Editing registry for win8dpiscalling and logpixels does no help. In small size, the texts are always jagged.